# How to get element by ID based on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, getelementbyid

I have a few images on a page that I am trying to have open in a modal when they are clicked.  I am using `document.getElementById()` to try and target the images' ID that was clicked.  So far I have tried to create a function that turns the clicked ID into a variable to pass into `document.getElementById(variable)`, but that doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a better way to go about this?

```js
function open_clicked(clicked_id) {
   var current_id = clicked_id;
}

document.getElementById(current_id);
```

```html
 <img id="Elk" src="images/elk.png" alt="Elk" onclick="open_clicked(this.id)">
 <img id="Deer" src="images/deer.png" alt="Deer" onclick="open_clicked(this.id)">
```

Comment: current_id is a variable only visible to your open_clicked function.

Try putting var current_id outside of the function. That would be a good start.

Comment: instead of passing `this.id` into your `open_clicked`, you can pass through `this`, which will be the element (which means there is no need to access it via `document.getElementById()`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `this.id` as the argument to `open_clicked` function, you can just pass `this` as the argument which will give to access to the element that was clicked.

Here is a simple demonstration.

```js
function open_clicked(currImg) {
   // you do not need to call document.getElementById again 
   // currImg is the img element that was clicked
   var currentImgId = currImg.getAttribute("id")
   console.log(currentImgId)
}
```

```html
<img id="Elk" src="images/elk.png" alt="Elk" onclick="open_clicked(this)"/> 
<img id="Deer" src="images/deer.png" alt="Deer" onclick="open_clicked(this)"/>
```